# Continuously deploy (CD) SignalR console app to Azure App Services

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-webjobs, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying Azure App Services. I've set up a build pipeline in Azure DevOps which builds and pushes my image to Docker Hub and then publishes `docker-compose.yml` as an artifact.

My release pipeline takes the `docker-compose.yml` and feeds it to the "Azure Web App for Container" task which succeeds. But the bot goes down and doesn't get back up after the deployment unless I access `http://<myappname>.azurewebsites.net`, then it starts and is of the latest pushed version. So everything seems to work, except the "restart" or `docker-compose up`.

I've been reading that I want to add a WebJob to my app service, but since I am using a Linux host I cannot seem to configure this. I've tried adding a `curl` task after deployment, but this probably executes too early.

Any ideas on how I would get to solve this last piece of the puzzle to have a simple CI/CD environment?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is zero out of the box support for hosting WebJobs in a Linux hosted app service. I've heard there's a hacky way of doing it (I'll have to find the post) but since it's not supported out of the gate, there's no guarantee it'll work.